# is a script a program being run under the current shell or a child shell?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu, centos, rhel

I am confused with regards to the following -
if I execute a script or run a program in the current shell by typing on its name

1. it searches in the $PATH variable, to find the location of the executable
2. once it finds it, does it run the executable in the current shell or will spawn a child shell/process to run the executable ?

I believe a new child process will be spawned to run the executable, but having said that, how does the child process know (the path to the executable) to run the executable ? — if I amended the PATH in the parent shell so that it can find the executable (using only PATH=$PATH:/newpath/to/executable)  but not doing an export

```
e.g., &mdash; I did not do an export here
$ PATH=$PATH:/path/to/executable
$ executable
```

When the parent shell finds the executable, what does it do next (spawn a child process? run the executable?). But again, how does the child process find the executable when the edited PATH environment is not exported to it

Comment: Is the first line of your shell script a `#!` line, or a line that is just `#`, or something else?

Comment: it is actually sqlplus, a binary executable.  when i type sqlplus, it is actually able to locate the executable. but it prompt me that some of the environment variables are not set properly - which leads me to think that the child process might need to access some public(env) variables, but again brought me to think - how does the child process even locate the executable in the 1st place ?  does the child process run the executable or ? (which lead to this question)

Answer (score 3):

It's not usually the parent that searches `$PATH`. It's usually the kernel.

Internally, spawning a new process is a `fork` 
(creates a new process but keeps running the current code; the parent and child each usually go into their own `if` branch) followed by an [exec*](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp) call (replaces the current process image with a new process image) with optional stuff (such as filedescriptor redirections or signal settings) in between.

The [exec*](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp) `p` members of the exec family (the exec family is just about doing the same thing in different ways) make the kernel search the `$PATH` environment variable when resolving an argument that doesn't have a slash in it.

Once the path is resolved, the kernel tries to run it as a binary, resorting to the shebang line if the former fails and the executable does have a shebang line. If the shebang line is used, the interpreter specified in it is run and passed the resolved path.

Answer (score 1):

There is difference between subshell and child process. What you are asking is about subshell.

Whenever parent shell finds executable it spawns a subshell, subshell have access to all variables of parent shell. That's why variable PATH is accessible to subshell also.

When parent shell spawns a child process then access to variables is restricted in child process.

You can check by following command.

unset a; a=1
(echo "a is $a in the subshell")
sh -c 'echo "a is $a in the child shell"'

for more information refer link [subshell info](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SubShell?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryShell%5Cb%29)